# How to check the last array element and change the button image

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

How to get check change the button image if it reach the last element of the array and perform  to start from first on click that button?
Here my code,Please help me

```
-(IBAction)changenext:(id)sender
{
static int j = 0;
backimg.enabled=TRUE;
if(sender == nextimg)
    j++;
else if(sender == backimg)
    j--;
if (j >= arcount)
{
    j = 0;
}
else if(j < 0)
{
    j = arcount - 1;
}
imager.image=[arimage objectAtIndex:j];  

}
```

What change should i made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i can not clearly understand what you asking but simply you get last element of `NSArray` with this code :-

`[myArray lastObject]`

For Example:-

`NSString *str = [myArray lastObject]`